# 'the page has expired due to inactivity please refresh the page' in laravel website developing in termux

Tags: php, laravel

i am developing a laravel website using termux. I have configure database using termux mariadb. database migration done. all set. but problem accruing during register page. register page opening but can't register it shows

> the page has expired due to inactivity please refresh the page

after submitting form. register and login page working well earlier. but from few days it's not working. may be problem occurring from config files or .env. I have tried many possibility. but never success.

Answer (score 1):

It's the CSRF error. If you have a form in your page, you have to add scrf field. See [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf)

Answer (score 1):

It's the CSRF error, you need to add csrf field to form

```
{{csrf_field}}
```

or

```
<input name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" type='hidden'>
```

Comment: I tried this but no okk